# How to generate the posterior predictive distribution for hierarchal model in PYMC3

Tags: bayesian, python, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

See [iPython notebook for full example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/markdregan/e8376040266a7eb42c34)

The below stochastic node `y_pred` enables me to generate the posterior predictive distribution:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha', alpha=.1, beta=.1)
    mu = pm.Gamma('mu', alpha=.1, beta=.1)
    y_pred = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_pred', mu=mu, alpha=alpha)
    y_est = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_est', mu=mu, alpha=alpha, observed=messages['time_delay_seconds'].values)

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.Metropolis(start=start)
    trace = pm.sample(20000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)
```

And the posterior predictive distribution plot:

[image]

Solution #1:
@inversion points out that the shape parameter must be provided.

Problem #2:
The samples from the posterior predictive are not correct. They get stuck at 0 or 1. Any ideas how to resolve this? I have only been able to reproduce this issue with hierarchal models.

[See ipython notebook with issue reproduced](https://gist.github.com/markdregan/61581d05c14a30e3a6bc).

[image]

Comment: I think the traceback is cut off. Can you paste the full one? Also, if you upload a NB that can run stand-alone it would go a long way in enabling others to help you.

Comment: Sure thing @twiecki, I've created a sample NB with error reproduced: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/markdregan/e8376040266a7eb42c34. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer below, but I'm interested to know why `Metropolis(start=start)` works in the above code, and fails when I try to use it (unexpected kwd error). `pm.__version__ = 3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchical model works if you specify the shape of `y_pred`.

```py
y_pred = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_pred', 
                             mu=mu[people_idx], 
                             alpha=alpha[people_idx],
                             shape=people.shape)
```

Here's the trace:

[image]

And the posterior predictive plot (after the appropriate flattening):

```
y_pred = trace[burn::thin].get_values('y_pred').ravel()
```

[image]

You can, of course, use `people_idx`  to compare posterior predictive plots of specific individuals.

**EDIT:** Noting that `y_pred` takes a long time to snap out of a value of 1.

[image]

Comment: Note: I worked off of the linked IPython notebook, which is why the distributions appear to be different and the variable names are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks @inversion, But the traceplots show issues. Have a look at this ipython notebook. All values for y_est are 1. See: https://gist.github.com/markdregan/61581d05c14a30e3a6bc

Comment: I don't understand exactly why, but `y_pred` takes a very long time to break out from a value of 1. See my full trace in the edit.

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by the priors. Gamma(.1, .1) suggests that `alpha` and `mu` are relatively large. When I constrict priors to Uniform(0,100) `y_pred` becomes unstuck.

Answer (score 3):

Second @inversion's answer. Note that there is (as of 5 minutes ago) proper support for drawing random samples directly from random variables. Here is an example of how to do this: http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/posterior_predictive/